# No funciona TAB despues de oprimir ENTER en NETBEANS 12.6

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-12

acabo de instalar NETBEANS 12.6 y cuando escribo una línea de código y salto de línea con <kbd>ENTER</kbd> el cursor se queda al principio de la linea siguiente y no funciona la tecla <kbd>TAB</kbd> ni se alinea con la línea anterior según el código que tenga escrito.
Tengo que avanzar con espacios y recién cuando escribo algo vuelve a funcionar TAB.
Estoy escribiendo una clase java (archivo *.java),

Comment: también tengo la versión de netbeans 12.5 con el JDK 8, pero me está pasando que cuando uso una vez un atajo y presiono tab me funciona bien, (por ejemplo Sca = Scanner teclado ...) pero al tratar de hacerlo por segunda vez no me sale el código, les ha pasado esto a ustedes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es un [bug de la versión 12.6](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-6281), lo que sugieren es que vuelvas a la versión 12.5 o uses un JDK más actual (mayor al JDK8). Yo uso el JDK8 así que opté por usar el Netbeans 12.5 y **solucionó el problema**, ya puedo tabular líneas en blanco. No he probado instalar un JDK más actual que el JDK8 por lo que no te podría asegurar que funcione lo segundo.

De todas formas te dejo el link de la versión 12.5 aquí:

https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb125/nb125.html

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y perdón, no alcance a probar la 12.5 porque volvi a la version 11.3 donde todo me funcionaba bien. Probaré en un tiempo la última revisión 12 cuando parezca mas estable. Que raro un bug en algo tan básico y que salta de inmediato.

Answer (score 1):

Estaba con el mismo problema, y gracias a [la respuesta de francisco](/a/510617) ya sé cual es la razón; de todas formas si no cambiaste de versión de IDE, lo que estaba haciendo yo era terminar de escribir el código y con <kbd>Alt+Mayús+F</kbd> lo dejaba con la indentación correcta.